# cannot access to constant variable in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5, constants, laravel-blade

i want to seperate my string in constant folder , i create some files to define my constant , but when i want to access them , nothing show in blade , controller and so on , i try to access with this syntax in blade

```
  {{config('constants.welcomeConstants.title')}}
```

but nothing show in blade , please help me , i seperate all string and now i have no text in my web application

my constant file is :

```
 <?php

     return [

             'title' => 'test'

           ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// /config/constants.php

return [
    'welcome' => [
        'hello' => 'Hello',
    ],
];

// Access config value
config('constants.welcome.hello');
```

Comment: i create folder in my confog file , how can i access to it ?

Comment: That makes no sense. You create a file e.g. `constants.php` in the `config` directory. Look at the example above.

Answer (score -1):

just use

```
php artisan config:clear or php artisan config:cache
```

Comment: Could you explain in which way those actions would answer the question ?

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.